# How to get python import dependency graph for project in pycharm?

Tags: python, graph, import, pycharm

In pycharm, I have project a structure that looks like:

```
src/message/hello.py
src/planet/world.py
```

`src`, `src/message`, and `src/planet` each have a `__init__.py` file too.

Now, `hello.py` imports `planet.world.py`.  Can pycharm generate a visual graph showing an arrow from `hello.py` to `world.py` ? Is there a plugin that can do it?

Now obviously, my project has more files than that.  I'd like to be able to give pycharm the instructions, "here's all my py files, generate an import-dependency graph, exclude any modules that are not on this list, so things like standard python packages should not be in the graph"

I am also interested in seeing a graph down to the class and method level, but that is too much information right now.  I am focused on graphs at the module level, like the one above.

I searched the pycharm plugin market, and I got plenty of false positives.

Thanks.